# Two text html text inputs in two different places on the page with the same submit id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, razor

So I have a page called Index.cshtml

I have this input in a form with the id "cvr":

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SendMailAsACompany", "Contract", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cvr" }))
   {
    <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.StudentId name="studentId" />
    <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId name="companyId" />
    <input type="hidden" value=@Html.ViewData.Model.ApplicationId name="applicationId"/>


       if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId)
       {

           <input type="text" name="companyCVR" placeholder="Indsæt CVR-nr."/>
       }

   }
```

and at the bottom of the page I have the submit button with the id above ("cvr") where I am trying to add two more forms to pass on to the controller (repFirstName and repLastName):

```
 @if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId)
         {
            using (Html.BeginForm("SendMailAsACompany", "Contract", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cvr" }))
            {

                    <input type="text" name="repFirstName" placeholder="Indsæt fornavn" />
                    <input type="text" name="repLastName" placeholder="Indsæt lastnavn" />

            }
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('#cvr').submit();" class="btn btn-success" />
          }
```

However they will not pass on submit, only the first value (the CPR above). However if I have all three values at the start, they will pass successfully.

How can I have the input in both places and still be able to submit and pass the data to the controller? Do I need two separate forms/ids ?

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: what does this mean? should the second form have for example the id "cvr2" ? how can I make the same submit button onclick to submit both of them?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your question, do you have one form with two inputs with the same `id` with a single submit or something else?

Comment: If the inputs are in separate places just have the button call a javascript function that gets the values from both fields, each with a unique id.

Comment: why don't you put everything inside one Html.BeginForm instead of two? As you want to submit both forms at same time, this approach makes more sense to me. BTW, every ID should be unique.

Comment: I have two forms the first one has one text input, the second one has two text inputs. I want all 3 text inputs to be submitted from the same button.

Comment: @RodrigoLeite because I have a lot of text between them, wont that affect anything?

Comment: @crystyxn it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: But I have another form between these two.

Comment: Nasty, submitting multiple forms with one submit button - that's really bad design and not great usability

Comment: this is bad usability. How will the user know that they must type in two separate forms in two separate places on the screen, and then it will submit all the information at the same time? Every user in the world will expect that they are two separate forms for two separate purposes

Comment: Well it is just a bunch of text between the two text inputs, then a submit button at the end, is that bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one form is required, remove the second form declaration and associate element with form using [`form` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#attr-form) which is defined at the bottom of page.

> The form attribute is used to associate an input, select, or textarea element with a form (known as its form owner).

```
@if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == Html.ViewData.Model.CompanyId)
{
    <input type="text" name="repFirstName" placeholder="Indsæt fornavn" form="cvr"/>
    <input type="text" name="repLastName" placeholder="Indsæt lastnavn" form="cvr"/>
    <button form="cvr" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: the submit button doesn't do anything now?

Comment: Try once with `<button form="cvr" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

If your generated HTML results in multiple elements that have the same ID, and then you have some inline javascript like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('#cvr').submit();" />
```

Then the above javascript will work only for the first `#cvr`

That is one example of why you cannot / must not have multiple elements on the page with the same ID.

You must refactor your code to only use one element with any given ID. *If need to have multiple elements with same moniker, use a `class`* - so your javascript would become:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('.cvr').submit();" />
```

and your generated HTML would be `class="cvr"` instead of `id="cvr"`

Alternately, you could ensure that each of your forms uses a different ID, such as `id="cvr1"`, `id="cvr2"`, `id="cvr3"` and then your javascript could be:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('#cvr1, #cvr2, #cvr3').submit();" />
```